# JSON response return HTML inside a Loop

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have this function in Laravel 5.1

```
public function calcolaKilometri()
    {

    $partenza = Input::get('partenza');
    $destinazione = Input::get('destinazione');
    $distanceMatrix = new DistanceMatrix(new Client(), new GuzzleMessageFactory()); 
    $response = $distanceMatrix->process(new DistanceMatrixRequest(
        [$partenza], 
        [$destinazione]
    )); 

        foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
        foreach ($row->getElements() as $element) {
        $distance = $element->getDistance();
        $text = $distance->text;
        $value = $distance->value;
        $data = ['text' => $text, 'value' => $value];       
        return \Response::json($data);  
            }       
        }

    }
```

need to return to Ajax JSON data but this function return plain HTML response, because we are in a forech loop. How i can do the trick?

Comment: "but this function return plain HTML response, because we are in a forech loop." makes no sense.

Comment: Of coruse this is the problem. The parse returnif to get result 2 foreach loop but result is 1. Inside each loop. I need to pass variable outside the loop

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're saying but I assume you want to return all of the data found when looping through your result set in a single JSON response.

Try something like this:

```
// Your previous code...

// Initialise a $data array here, that we're going to fill with data
$data = [];

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    foreach ($row->getElements() as $element) {
        $distance = $element->getDistance();
        $text = $distance->text;
        $value = $distance->value;

        // Append the new set of data to your array
        $data[] = ['text' => $text, 'value' => $value];       
    }       
}

// Return the data as JSON only when we've filled it with everything
return response()->json($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This...

```
$json = json_encode($data);
return \Response::json($json);
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved using sessions. If someone have the same issue:

```
public function calcolaKilometri()
    {

    $partenza = Input::get('partenza');
    $destinazione = Input::get('destinazione');
    $distanceMatrix = new DistanceMatrix(new Client(), new GuzzleMessageFactory()); 
    $response = $distanceMatrix->process(new DistanceMatrixRequest(
        [$partenza], 
        [$destinazione]
    )); 
    foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
        foreach ($row->getElements() as $element) {
            $text = $element->getDistance()->getText();
            $value = $element->getDistance()->getValue();
            \Session::put('testo', $text);
            \Session::put('valore', $value);
        }       
    }



// Return the data as JSON only when we've filled it with everything
    $testo = \Session::get('testo');
    $valore = \Session::get('valore');
    $result = ['text' => $testo, 'value' => $valore];       
        return \Response::json($result); 

    }
```